# At what moment does git finish its operations on execution?

Tags: git, go

I have an utility in Go that runs commits checkouts via `os/exec` and then does some operations on files from the commit.

I suspect that at the moment this command returns its return code:

```
_, err := exec.Command("git", "-C", sourceDir, "checkout", hash).Output()
```

The whole file tree is up to date in the folder and I can do whatever I want with the files, without the need to wait for some operations to finish in background.

What if it's a very large repository, where one commit differs much from another one and it takes time to sync deleted/added/modified files when switching from one commit to another?

Can I run my operations right after `git checkout` returns `0`?

Comment: You get a return code when a process exits. What else would it be doing if it's no longer running?

Comment: @JimB, garbage collection. Although I don't think a checkout can trigger that since it doesn't modify the repository.

Comment: @Peter: I don't think git forks a new process to run GC asynchronously. If there was anything operating on the repo after `git` exits that could prevent you from using the files, it wouldn't be safe to use from the cli either.

Comment: @JimB, [gc.autoDetach](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.1.0) controls this and is enabled by default.

Comment: What I like about SO is that even if I get more downvotes than expected or average, I still can extract a solution from comments or answers. Thanks mates!

Comment: @Peter: thanks for the info (though it still does not effect the checked out files, nor a checkout in general)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout` does not exit until the checkout is completed (or has failed).

Comments about auto-gc in the background are not particularly relevant here, since auto-gc is not related to whether the checkout has finished.  For that matter, `git checkout` does not run `git gc --auto`: there is no point since `git checkout` does not create new Git objects.  A reasonably current list of things that *do* invoke `git gc --auto` (as of about 2.18) is:

- `git am`
- `git commit`
- `git fetch`
- `git merge`
- `git receive-pack` (servers)
- `git rebase`